# Strange behavior with backbone models/collections, How do I get the id from a freshly created model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am getting some weird behavior when creating models with backbone.js and rails 3.0.7 (and coffeescript).

I create a model with

```
@model = @collection.create
  param : a_param
  param : another_param
```

This saves to rails fine and the return object is what I expect (when I console.log @model it returns a proper looking backbone model with id, cid, attributes...etc).

When I console.log @model.id it returns undefined (Even though it was there in console.log @model).

When I console.log @collection it returns the expected collection, but when I console.log @collection.models it returns an empty array.

When I load the @collection via json in the (rails)page:

```
( json_from_the_page : #{@collection.to_json} )   

@collection = new CollectionName()
@collection.reset options.json_from_the_page
```

and console.log @collection.models everything works fine so it must be something to do with saving to the server?

Any ideas, or places I should look in the backbone code to further debug?

Comment: furthermore I can access model.attributes.a_param_i_saved, but not @model.attributes.id, which appears when I log model.attributes.

Comment: even furthermore, if I set it up in the success of a model.save() then it returns the id fine, so it must have something to do with the code after the original create running before the server gets a chance to return the correct id?

Comment: Be sure to look at the status of the variables using the in browser debugger (you can set a breakpoint in your code with `debugger;`).  I have found that console.log frequently displays the future status of variables, and can make debugging difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source code for Backbone, the ID of an object is only set if it receives the ID during construction.  *Rails* is setting the ID, so when you ask for it from rails, you get one, but you don't get one when you build a new object.

This is by design; backbone assumes that the canonical ID will be set by the server.  So for a "freshly made" model, the ID isn't set automatically (and the model's method `isNew()` returns `true`).

If you want the freshly made model to have an ID, save it immediately (and don't act on it until the save returns) so your server can provide an ID.  If you have a programmatic ID that is reliable on the client side, override `initialize()` to provide one during construction if one is not provided in the attributes field.

Comment: Brilliant thanks!  This was exactly it, it was a conceptual leap that I needed to make (you have to wait for response before carrying on).
I found @collection.bind('add', (m)=> ...) pretty useful as => in coffeescript let me access things in the scope I needed (where @collection was hanging out).  Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I was trying to save a model and add it to a collection. Although this did work, I couldn't do any manipulation to the newly created model until I refreshed the page. This was happening because although I was saving the model, it still didn't have the id created by the rails backend.

In order to fix this problem, I needed to save the model, set the id of the new model based on the rails response, and THEN add it to the collection. Take a look at the sample code below (written in coffeescript). I am declaring a success function for the model (as well as an error function). In the success function I am getting the ID in @model['attributes']['0'] which has the stored rails response. Your setup could be a little different.

```
attrs =
    name: 'model_name'

options =
    success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) =>
        @model.set
            id: @model['attributes']['0']['id']
        @collection.add(@model)
    error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) =>
        alert 'Failed to create model'

@model.save(attrs, options)
```